# Adding XElement in to Existing XML File

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, linq-to-xml

I have done lots of research and everywhere I look it says this should work. Every time I run my program it throughs the following error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when the program reaches xdoc.Root.Element.....

This snippet is in the main program.

```
    private void btn_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Certification cert = new Certification();
        cert.CreateCertification(txt_certlevel.Text, txt_certnum.Text, txt_certagency.Text, dtp_cert.Value);
        xmlfunction.Add(cert);
    }
```

And this snippet is in a Class file seperate from the main program file.

```
    public void Add(Certification certification)
    {

            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(pathString);

            xdoc.Root.Element("Digital_Scuba_Log").Element("Diver").Element("Certifications").Add(new XElement("Certification_Card",
                new XElement("Level", certification.Level),
                new XElement("Agency", certification.Agency),
                new XElement("Number", certification.Number),
                new XElement("Date", certification.Date.ToString())
                ));
            xdoc.Save(pathString);
    }
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: Debugging is your friend. Check where that `null` value is coming from to start with.

Comment: It appears it is in the xdoc document type. How do I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that "Digital_Scuba_Log" is the root node of your XML.  In that case, when you use xdoc.Root, you're already traversing into that node.  Here are 2 ways to do it based on your XML.

"Digital_Scuba_Log" as your root node:

```
XDocument xDoc2 = XDocument.Parse("<Digital_Scuba_Log><Diver><Certifications></Certifications></Diver></Digital_Scuba_Log>");

xDoc2.Element("Digital_Scuba_Log")
  .Element("Diver")
  .Element("Certifications")
  .Add(new XElement("Certification_Card",
    new XElement("Level", certification.Level),
    new XElement("Agency", certification.Agency),
    new XElement("Number", certification.Number),
    new XElement("Date", certification.Date.ToString())
));
```

With a root node on your xml:

```
XDocument xDoc1 = XDocument.Parse("<root><Digital_Scuba_Log><Diver><Certifications></Certifications></Diver></Digital_Scuba_Log></root>");

xDoc1.Root.Element("Digital_Scuba_Log")
  .Element("Diver")
  .Element("Certifications")
  .Add(new XElement("Certification_Card",
    new XElement("Level", certification.Level),
    new XElement("Agency", certification.Agency),
    new XElement("Number", certification.Number),
    new XElement("Date", certification.Date.ToString())
));
```